# Change progress of CSS3 animation by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I'm wondering if it is possible to manipulate the 'progress' of a CSS3 animation. Let's say you have the following css:

```
#myBox {
  animation: fadein 2s ease-in-out 0 1 forwards;
}
@keyframes fadein {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Now after the page loads, `#myBox` will have `opacity: 0;` and after 2 seconds it will have `opacity: 1;`. Can I somehow 'manipulate' the progress of the animation by JavaScript? Say I want to start the animation at 50%, so at page load it will be `opacity: 0.5;` and after 1 second it has `opacity: 1;`

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: use `animation-delay: -1s`  which is 50% of `2s`.

Comment: Your example can be done with pure css, like Mr_Green showed you. Not sure why do you even want to use JS ?

Comment: Yes, explaining why you need JS and why you can't just use a new CSS class with the animation you want would make your question clearer

Comment: The start point of the animation should depend on other things. That's why I need JavaScript ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the keyframes, for example:

```html
//this will start at 0.5 and keep it half way (1 second) and then aniate the fade to 1

@keyframes fadein {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

//you can do all sorts like blinking etc

@keyframes fadein {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```